# SAML certificate, private-key

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, okta

So I am implementing SSO over SAML2.0 for our application. We are using [saml2-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saml2-js) on our side and we are doing SP initiated SSO.

The implementation is ready and it is working however there are a few parts I struggle wrapping my head around.

1. saml2-js requires you to provide a private-key and a certificate on the ServiceProvider instance -> https://www.npmjs.com/package/saml2-js#serviceprovideroptions I don't understand what these are used for and saml2-js don't provide any meaningful description about them. I tried to find out by understanding from a SAML point of view but I still don't know.
2. As an IdP, Okta is the target and after setting up SAML in Okta, Okta provides it's certificate. Now I understand that part because Okta will sign the Response and on our side, the SP uses that certificate to ensure that the Assertion came from a/the trusted party. But how does Okta make sure that the request came from a trusted party? I thought the certificate saml2-js requires from us will be used for that, but as it turned out this assumption was false because Okta doesn't get our certificate in any ways
3. When setting up SAML in Okta ([okta guide](https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/saml-application-setup/overview/)) in point 6 they require you to fill the Audience URI which by default is the SP entity_id. But this can be an arbitrary value right? What is this used for and why is this mandatory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The service provider requires a private key if it's signing SAML messages or decrypting SAML assertions. If neither is the case, a private key shouldn't be required.
2. I don't believe Okta requires the SAML authn request to be signed. This isn't unusual. If the SAML authn request isn't signed, the IDP can't be sure who sent the message but this normally wouldn't present any security issues. If you click the Show Advanced Settings link in the Okta configuration you get the option of supplying your certificate. However, this is only required for signing the logout messages.
3. The audience URI identifies the intended recipient of the SAML response which should be the SP. It's part of the SAML protocol and as such you would expect the SP to check its value against the SP's entity ID. If you take a look at the SAML specification it talks about its purpose as helping to uphold warranty exclusions in a court of law. You can draw your own conclusions as to how useful this is.